# Does MakeTableView work with field_info in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing

```
gp.Execute(new MakeTableView()
                    {
                        in_table = $@"Database Connections\os@gisuat.sde\TESTGIS.SOME_POLY",
                        out_view = "SOME_POLY",
                        where_clause = "STATUS = 'INCLUDED'",
                        workspace = defaultSDEWorkspace
                    }, null);
```

Please consider the code above. I can run it perfectly and get my results in a temp view. However, there is another option - `field_info` which require an `object` type and I have tried to fit different types of instance into this parameter but it still fail...

The type I have tried: `ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FieldInfoSetClass`, `ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FieldInfoClass`

I don't see any standard doc about this method and option... Anyone can save me out? Provided a sample code snippet that I have attempted

```
                    var fieldInfoSet = new FieldInfoSetClass();
                    fieldInfoSet.Add("Drawing_number", new FieldInfoClass()
                    {
                        Alias = "DN",
                        Visible = true,
                        ValueAsRatio = false
                    });

                    var tableView = gp.Execute(new MakeTableView()
                    {
                        in_table = $@"Database Connections\os@gisuat.sde\TIS2GIS.XANTHUS_DATASET\TIS2GIS.XANTHUS_POLY",
                        out_view = "XATNHUS_POLY2",
                        where_clause = "Drawing_number = 'INCLUDED'",
                        workspace = defaultSDEWorkspace,
                        field_info = fieldInfoSet
                    }, null);
```

Also, I cannot get any useful information from exception message/error code.

- H_RESULT: -2147467259
- Message: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree this is not well documented. I tried the FieldInfoSet, ValueTable but eventually hit upon the GPFieldInfo object.

I worked out it was that by looking at the python snippet you get from running the Make Table View geoprocessing tool in ArcMap

If had returned:

```
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(in_table="C:/Scratch/mst.shp", out_view="myNewTable", where_clause='"FID" > 10', workspace="", field_info="FID FID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;EA_CODE_20 EA_CODE_20 VISIBLE NONE;SpanLength SpanLength VISIBLE NONE")
```

The semi-colon spaced out list set off alarm bells and eventually the only ArcObject class that would accept those values I saw was the [IGPFieldInfo](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGPFieldInfo_AddField.htm) interface.

Here is some VBA code to show you it working.

```vb
Public Sub CreateTable()
    Dim pgp As IGeoProcessor
    Set pgp = New GeoProcessor
    pgp.AddOutputsToMap = True
    
    Dim pgpFI As IGPFieldInfo
    Set pgpFI = New GPFieldInfo
    With pgpFI
        .AddField 1, "FID", "FID", True, esriGPFieldInfoSplitRuleNone
        .AddField 1, "SHAPE", "shape", True, esriGPFieldInfoSplitRuleNone
        .AddField 1, "EA_CODE_20", "EA_CODE_20", False, esriGPFieldInfoSplitRuleNone
        .AddField 1, "SpanLength", "zippy", True, esriGPFieldInfoSplitRuleNone
    End With
    
    Dim pVA As IVariantArray
    Set pVA = New VarArray
    With pVA
        .Add "C:\Scratch\mst.shp"
        .Add "myNewTable2"
        .Add """" + "FID" + """" + " > 10"
        .Add ""
        .Add pgpFI
    End With
    Dim pGR As IGeoProcessorResult
    Set pGR = pgp.Execute("MakeTableView_management", pVA, Nothing)
    
End Sub
```

WARNING:

1] The Index value seems to be ignored, I have just put ones in but even if you put 0 to 3 or 1 to 4, same result...

2] I deliberately set the new name to be "zippy" but this is ignored, seems to be a bug?

Comment: Instant LIKE AND ACCEPT.   THANK YOU